# how to increment month and year from calendar in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, increment

i am trying to increment date and year from calendar, but it is incrementing only one value which means (it is incrementing from jan to feb, but it is not incrementing after feb) my requirement is to incrementing upto 12 month and also simultaneously year has to increment. could you please tell me how to resolve this issue this is my code

```
- (IBAction)right:(id)sender {


    [datearray removeAllObjects];
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    date = [cal dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth value:1 toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM YYYY"];
    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    yar.text=stringFromDate;
    NSString *y1=yar.text;
    NSArray * arr = [y1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSString *m=arr[0];
    NSString *yy=arr[1];


    spinner =  [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    spinner.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;

    [spinner setLabelText:@"Loading....."];

    [spinner setLabelFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];

    [spinner show:YES];

    //[self.coutweek setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",week]];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://edvancepreschoolsadminpanel.com/viverobranch/json/json_lunch.php?key=agile89rise98&food=%@&month=%@&year=%@&username=%@",scl,m,yy,temp];


    NSLog(@"the url string==%@",urlString);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    NSLog(@"the str==%@",jsonString);

    NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@",results);

    luncharray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *array=[results objectForKey:@"lunch_menu"];



    for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {

        NSString *dat =[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"date"];
        NSString *mon =[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"month"];
        NSString *yea =[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"year"];
        NSString *luh =[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"food"];
        NSString *tim =[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"time"];

        ipadlunch *myimg =[[ipadlunch alloc]initWithdat:dat andmon:mon andyea:yea andlunch:luh andtime:tim];
        NSLog(@"%@",myimg);
        [luncharray addObject:myimg];
        // NSLog(@"the field==%@",videoarray1);
    }
```

Comment: Increment from calendar? You're always adding a month to the current date? I don't really understand what you're asking and you should just show the relevant code, the HUD, spinner and JSON stuff seem irrelevant.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, or what you'd like your code to accomplish. What do you mean by incrementing date and year?

Comment: @JamesFrost i  have two buttons one for increment another for decrement  if i click increment button, my year should increment(for ex: 2014 to 2015 to 2016 and so on) what i have to do for that